# What's the easiest way to append RTF content from a MemoryStream into an XamRichTextEditor

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, rtf, rich-text-editor

I am trying to merge the RTF context from a standard System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox control, and append it to the end of the current RTF context of a XamRichTextEditor control.  Currently, my following code is throwing a null reference exception on the first line I try to reference the temporary XamRichTextEditor's "ActiveDocumentView" even though I would assume after calling the Document.Load it should be initialized and populated with stuff.  I'm open to approaching this from a different method, it just seemed the Copy/Paste idea was going to be the simplest.

Code:

```
                byte[] byteSig = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtfContextText);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteSig))
                {
                    XamRichTextEditor tmpRichTextBox = new XamRichTextEditor();
                    tmpRichTextBox.Document.Load(RtfSerializationProvider.Instance, ms); // put current email body into memory stream
                    tmpRichTextBox.ActiveDocumentView.Selection.SelectAll();    // select all content
                    tmpRichTextBox.ActiveDocumentView.Selection.Copy();         // copy content into Clipboard
                    txtTextEditor.ActiveDocumentView.Selection.Paste();         // append Clipboard content into main XamRichTextEditor control
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build an answer to my own questions, but I was never able to get the copy and paste method to fully work for me (I got some of the content from one pasted into the other, but linebreaks and embedded images seemed to be ignored in the outcome).

I ended up having to manually work with the 2 RichTextBox contexts' raw data directly.  To do this I located where in the Target context I wanted to insert the other, and from the other context I stripped off all but the outermost grouping (to avoid duplicating the root node).  I then loaded the Target RichTextBox's document with this concatenated version.  (sample code below for anyone who ran into the same issue I did.  Hope it can help someone eventually.)

```
 // get string encoded version of body
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    txtTextEditor.Document.Save(RtfSerializationProvider.Instance, ms);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        strRtfCurrBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

// find end and then the beginning of second-to-last grouping
                strRtfSignature = strRtfSignature.Remove(strRtfSignature.LastIndexOf('}'));
                int intCheck = PibsEmailer.RtfFindStartpoint(strRtfSignature, strRtfSignature.LastIndexOf('}'));

                if (intCheck < 0)
                {
                    // this should never happen unless the content of the signature is not in valid RTF format
                    throw new Exception("AddSignature Failed. Sig=\"" + Session.CurrentUser.EmailSignature + "\" , Body=\"" + strRtfCurrBody + "\"  IntCheck=" + intCheck);
                }

                strRtfSignature = strRtfSignature.Substring(intCheck);
                strRtfCurrBody = strRtfCurrBody.Insert(PibsEmailer.RtfFindLastParEnd(strRtfCurrBody), strRtfSignature);

                byte[] byteFullContent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strRtfCurrBody);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteFullContent))
                {
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    this.txtTextEditor.Selection.SelectAll();
                    this.txtTextEditor.Selection.Document.Load(RtfSerializationProvider.Instance, ms);
                }
```

and to help facilitate the handling of the RTF Formatted data I wrote the following two functions (referenced in the code above):

```
public static int RtfFindLastParEnd(string source)
    {
        int intLastPar = source.LastIndexOf("par}");
        if (intLastPar > 0)
        {
            intLastPar += 4; // add offset of "par}"
        }
        return intLastPar;
    }

    public static int RtfFindStartpoint(string source, int indexOfClosingBrace)
    {
        string workingString = source;
        int nestCount = 0;
        int currIndex = indexOfClosingBrace;

        while (currIndex > 0)
        {
            if (source[currIndex] == '}')
                nestCount++;
            else if (source[currIndex] == '{')
                nestCount--;

            if (nestCount == 0)
            {
                return currIndex;
            }
            currIndex--;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```